# Assigning a specific function to a more abstract function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have two Function types:

```
type AbstractFunc = (value: string) => boolean
type ConcreteFunc = (value1: 'hello') => boolean
```

Since I can assign a variable of the literal type `'hello'` to a variable of type `string`, I thought I can do the same with my two functions for example:

```
let z1: 'hello' = 'hello' as const
// No Error
let z2: string  = z1;

type AbstractFunc = (value: string) => boolean
type ConcreteFunc = (value1: 'hello') => boolean

let u: ConcreteFunc = null as any;

// Error: 
//       Type 'ConcreteFunc' is not assignable to type 'AbstractFunc'.
//       Types of parameters 'value1' and 'value' are incompatible.
//       Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"hello"'.
let z: AbstractFunc = u;
```

But I get the specified error message.

In my opinion this behaviour does not make sense. A Function that accepts a literal string as input type should be assignable to a more abstract function that accepts a regular string as input.

Are my assumptions wrong or is this a mistake made by typescript?

Comment: In other words: your assumptions are wrong. The inputs must be _at least as broad_, not narrower. The outputs must be _as most as broad_, not broader. Otherwise it's not assignable as it wouldn't be able to receive something a consumer would send (narrower inputs), or would send something a consumer wouldn't be able to receive (broader outputs).

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the clarification. This does makes sense. I think the only option I have in this case is to use a type-cast. Or do you have other suggestions?

Comment: The real question is: Why are you trying to do something that is not type-safe? You are presumably doing this to solve some *other problem*. Maybe include in the question what you are really trying to do?